# Jasper Report group footer not printing immediately after detail band

Tags: jasper-reports, report, ireport

I have introduced the group to the report.
I would like to make sure that group footer is printed immediately after detail section.
My group footer has 200 height therefore if there is less than 200 px left on current page, the group footer is mover over to the next page.

Is there a way to start group footer right after detail band (even though it will not fit on current page and part of it will be moved over to next page)

Please not ‘isSplitAllowed’ is set to true for the group footer band

I will appreciate your suggestions, thank you

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jasper reports? The latest version gives you 3 options for _slit type_ for bands (immediate, prevent, stretch). Maybe one of them can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the design like this:

[image: the design in iReport]

The height of textfields elements are equal the band's height.

The result will be:

[image: the result report in the pdf format]